Finding linearly independent rows from SVD
I have the SVD of matrix $A_{m\times n}$, $A=USV^H$. The rank of $A$ is $k$. I use $A^{\prime}_{k\times n}=(U_{m\times k})^H A_{m \times n}$ to estimate $A$. How can I find these $k$ independent rows of $A^\prime$ in $A$ using SVD? I can't use Gaussian elimination, because the order and index of the rows is important and I don't want them to change.

what do you mean by "find"? The rows of $A'$ are combinations of the rows of $A$

@Exodd I wanted to reduce rows of $A$ and just use $k$ number of most significant rows instead of $m$. So, I was wondering if there is a way to project back these $k$ rows from $A^\prime$ to $A$.
